# delete characters that are not letters, numbers, whitespace?

Tags: python-3.x

community,

I need to clean a string, so that it will contain only letters, numbers and whitespace.
The string momentarily consists of different sentences.

I tried:

```
for entry in s:
if not isalpha() or isdigit() or isspace:
    del (entry)
else: s.append(entry) # the wanted characters should be saved in the string, the rest should be deleted
```

I am using python 3.4.0

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: NameError: name 'isalpha' is not defined --- says python

Comment: you have to make it `entry.isalpha()`, it is an operation on a string. Same goes for digit and space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
clean_string = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum() or c.isspace())
```

It iterates through each character, leaving you only with the ones that satisfy at least one of the two criteria, then joins them all back together. I am using [`isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) to check for alphanumeric characters, rather than both `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` separately.

You can achieve the same thing using a [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
clean_string = filter(lambda c: c.isalnum() or c.isspace(), s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `or` does not work the way you think it works in English. Instead, you should do:

```
new_s = ''

for entry in s:
    if entry.isalpha() or entry.isdigit() or entry.isspace():
        new_s += entry

print(new_s)
```

Comment: `del` doesn't work like that either.. and if `s` is a string, it won't have an `append` method, and if it's a list, you shouldn't be appending to lists you're iterating over.

Comment: @DSM. Thank you. I was making the appropriate corrections still.

Comment: @DSM, I have corrected the code. Is it right now? Thank you